# Unable to extract value for xml tags

Tags: excel, vba

I am a new to vba and have a task to do at hand. I have written some unction but could not debug it properly. I have following string in xml format:

```
<!--?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?-->

<credentials>
    <mid>P</mid>
    <mpid>Q</mpid>
    <accid>R</accid>
    <accesskey>S</accesskey>
    <secretkey>T</secretkey>
</credentials>
```

and am trying to extract value corresponding to tag `mid`, `mpid`, `accid` etc.

Here is the subroutine I wrote:

```
Private Sub ExtractMWSCredentials(Text As String
    Set xmldoc = Nothing
    DoEvents
    Set xmldoc = Get_XML_DOMDocument_Object()
    xmldoc.LoadXML (Trim(Text))

    Set mId = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("mid").Item(0).Text
    Set mpId =  xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("mpid").Item(0).Text
    Set accid =  xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("accid").Item(0).Text
    Set accesskey = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("accesskey").Item(0).Text
End Sub
```

Everything is coming out to be empty. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't even get that code to compile.  You don't use the Set keyword to store a non-object value like Text.  You could code, for instance,

```
Set omId = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("mid").Item(0)
Debug.Print omId.Text
```

Also, mId is a reserved word so it can't be a variable name.  Here's one way you could do it.

```
Public Sub Extract()

    Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim sMid As String, sMpid As String
    Dim sAccid As String, sAccessKey As String

    Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xDoc.LoadXML "<!--?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?-->" & _
        "<credentials><mid>P</mid><mpid>Q</mpid><accid>R</accid>" & _
        "<accesskey>S</accesskey><secretkey>T</secretkey></credentials>"

    sMid = xDoc.getElementsByTagName("mid").Item(0).Text
    sMpid = xDoc.getElementsByTagName("mpid").Item(0).Text
    sAccid = xDoc.getElementsByTagName("accid").Item(0).Text
    sAccessKey = xDoc.getElementsByTagName("accesskey").Item(0).Text

    Debug.Print sMid, sMpid, sAccid, sAccessKey

End Sub
```

I don't use Set because I'm not storing the Item() in a variable, I'm storing the Item().Text in a variable.